# How to remove ONLY zoom buttons in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to remove only the zoom buttons in `highcharts` (not the date range selection boxes)

[image]

I used following options, but it removes date filter as well.

```
 rangeSelector: {
            inputEnabled: false,
            buttonTheme: {
                visibility: 'hidden'
            },
            labelStyle: {
                visibility: 'hidden'
            }
        }
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

config should be  `inputEnabled: true`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggwtqrvh/)

```
rangeSelector: {
        inputEnabled: true,
        buttonTheme: {
            visibility: 'hidden'
        },
        labelStyle: {
            visibility: 'hidden'
        }
    },
```